# Create Django app with no User model - 3.1.3 wants to migrate auth_user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration

I've got a Django application which has been happily humming along now for quite some time (2 years or so).

It's on 3.0.10 currently - when I tried to upgrade to 3.1.3, it says there was a migration for the `auth` application. No worries! Never been an issue before...

I ran `python manage.py migrate` and got the following error:

`"Cannot find the object "auth_user" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."`

Which, I suppose would be true because we do not have a `User` model at all in this application. There is no `auth_user` table, that is correct. In other apps we have an `AbstractUser` that routes to a table named: `org_user` - but again:

*this particular app (and project) do not have any `User` model associated with them*

Obviously this (apparently, *now*) leads to some issues.

Any thoughts on how to get around this? I thought about removing `auth` from installed apps and tried that but it led to more issues when trying to `runserver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake a migration using `--fake` option:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake auth
python manage.py migrate
```

But I suspect the error you get could be symptomatic of a project design issue, such as not setting properly [`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: There is no AUTH_USER_MODEL, that is correct. Thanks for the --fake flag, didn't realize that was a thing! I should clarify - after a long complicated thing: in production that table exists, so the migration works. Locally, it does not - the flag did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :- Run these commands :-

```
    python manage.py migrate auth

    python manage.py migrate
```

Solution 2 :-  Try to copy your Project in another folder and then run migrations.